# java.lang.IllegalArgumentExeception: column "distance" does not exist

Tags: android

**SQLiteOpenHelper.class**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private final static int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private final static String DB_NAME = "places.db";

    public DBHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String sql =
            "CREATE TABLE " + PlacesContract.Places.TABLE_NAME
            +"("
            + PlacesContract.Places._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
            + PlacesContract.Places.NAME + " TEXT ,"
            + PlacesContract.Places.ADDRESS + " TEXT, "
            + PlacesContract.Places.DISTANCE + " TEXT "
            +")";

        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + PlacesContract.Places.TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(sql);

        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

**FragmentA.class** :

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements OnClickListener, OnEditorActionListener, LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
View v;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider; 


public static FragmentA newInstance(){

    // create a fragment:
    FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();

    return fragmentA;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.a, container, false);

    ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);


    //Check Location

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    //criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    Log.d("\nProvider: ",  provider);

    Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if(lastKnownLocation == null){
        Log.d("No Location", provider);
    }
    else{
        Log.d(+ lastKnownLocation.getLatitude() + ", "
                + lastKnownLocation.getLongitude(), provider);
    }
    String lastLocation;
    if(lastKnownLocation != null)
    {
        lastLocation = lastKnownLocation.getLatitude() + ", "
        + lastKnownLocation.getLongitude();
    }
    else
    {
        lastLocation = "Location Not Detected";
    }
    //End Location 



    String[] from = {PlacesContract.Places.NAME, PlacesContract.Places.ADDRESS, PlacesContract.Places.DISTANCE};
    int[] to = {R.id.location_Name, R.id.location_Address, R.id.location_Distance};

    //String imgURL = PlacesContract.Places.ICON;
    String[]distance = {PlacesContract.Places.DISTANCE};
    Log.d("This is distance", Arrays.toString(distance));
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.itemlist_location, null, from, to, 0);


    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);


    Button btnSearch = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    EditText editSearch = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editSearch);

    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
    editSearch.setOnClickListener(this);



    return v;
}
```

**SearchPlaceService.Class**

```
public class SearchPlacesService extends IntentService{

private static final String TAG = "SearchPlacesService";

public SearchPlacesService(){
    super("SearchPlacesService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    String query = intent.getStringExtra("query");

    if(query == null || query.length() < 2){
        return;
    }

    getContentResolver().delete(PlacesContract.Places.CONTENT_URI, null, null);

    String result = GoogleAccess.searchPlace(query);
    Log.d(TAG, result);

    try {
        JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(result);

        JSONArray resultsArray = jsonResult.getJSONArray("results");

        for(int i=0; i<resultsArray.length(); i++){

            JSONObject place = resultsArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String name = place.getString("name");
            String address = place.getString("formatted_address");
            String lat = place.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng");
            String lng = place.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
            String distance = (lat + " " + lng);



            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(PlacesContract.Places.NAME, name);
            values.put(PlacesContract.Places.ADDRESS, address);
            values.put(PlacesContract.Places.DISTANCE, distance);


            getContentResolver().insert(PlacesContract.Places.CONTENT_URI, values);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**ERROR :**
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentExeception: column "distance" does not exist**

I'll be glad if someone could tell me what's the problem since I can't find it.

**EDIT : I added the comma and I stil get the same error.**

Comment: Title says column id, text says column distance. I'm confused.

Comment: like 90% of sqlite-android related questions, this is a typo.

Comment: After fixing your schema, uninstall your app / clear its data / upgrade db version. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a comma:

```
PlacesContract.Places.ADDRESS + " TEXT " <<<<<<<<
```

Comment: After added the comma I still have the same error, any ideas?

Comment: Nothing really obvious. But just to be sure: have you recreated the database i.e. removed the old file?